# Moment js get first and last day of current month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How do I get the first and last day and time of the current month in the following format in moment.js:

> 2016-09-01 00:00

I can get the current date and time like this:
`moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:m')` which will output in the above format.

However I need to get the date and time of the first and last day of the current month, any way to do this?

**EDIT:** 
My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month) one because that asks for a given month that the user already has whereas I am asking for the **current** month along with asking for a specific format of the date that is not mentioned in the other so called 'duplicate'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment JS start and end of given month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month)

Comment: Moment.js support the function to get the first and last day of month, you can get that for current month by : moment().startOf('month') and moment().endOf('month') .
I think you should view the answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month)

Comment: @TanLe Yes but this outputs in the following format: `Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)` I want the format as I've mentioned in my question

Comment: That function return the moment object for day, so you can use format to output with any format that you want. Like : moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').

Comment: @AuditeMarlow Nice try but the questions are slightly different as explained in my edit.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

In case anyone missed the comments on the original question, you can use built-in methods (works as of Moment 1.7):

```
const startOfMonth = moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
const endOfMonth   = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
```

Comment: Don't know why somebody deleted the original comments but the reason this was not the accepted answer was because it was posted many months after the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks @user3574492 not a big deal, thanks for clarification -  if you think this answer is the best one then I think it is possible to change it to the accepted answer, even if it was posted later.

Comment: `moment(1, "DD");` will return first day of current month

Comment: why we need `clone` here ?

Comment: .Clone() is needed since a lot of the functions will modify the moment date. One example is x = momentDate.add(1,"day"); momentDate will be modified here, adding one day as well as settting x. StartOf month will set the moment to the start of the month.

Comment: we are not mutating the variables here so clone() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 48):

There would be another way to do this:

```
var begin = moment().format("YYYY-MM-01");
var end = moment().format("YYYY-MM-") + moment().daysInMonth();
```

Answer (score 34):

You can do this without moment.js

A way to do this in native Javascript code :

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

firstDay = moment(firstDay).format(yourFormat);
lastDay = moment(lastDay).format(yourFormat);
```

Comment: This outputs in the default date format `Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)` not in the format I want it: `2016-09-01 00:00`

Comment: Use moment to format the date ... 
firstDay = moment(firstDay).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
lastDay = moment(lastDay).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

Comment: and how to get `startdate` and `enddate` of next month using this formula?

Answer (score 20):

moment ***startOf()*** and ***endOf()*** is the answer you are searching for..
For Example:-

```
moment().startOf('year');    // set to January 1st, 12:00 am this year
moment().startOf('month');   // set to the first of this month, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('week');    // set to the first day of this week, 12:00 am
moment().startOf('day');     // set to 12:00 am today
```

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you are using a Date range Picker to retrieve the dates. You could do something like to to get what you want.

```
$('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker({
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },
            startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
            endDate: moment()
        }, function (start, end) {
      alert( 'Date is between' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD h:m') + 'and' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD h:m')}
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple we can use [daysInMonth()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/) and [endOf()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/)

```
const firstDay = moment('2016-09-15 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:m').startOf('month').format('D')
const lastDay = moment('2016-09-15 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:m').endOf('month').format('D')
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into some issues because I wasn't aware that `moment().endOf()` mutates the input date, so I used this work around.

```js
let thisMoment = moment();
let endOfMonth = moment(thisMoment).endOf('month');
let startOfMonth = moment(thisMoment).startOf('month');
```

Comment: always use moment().clone(), if you want to use the same variables.

Answer (score 1):

First and Last Date of current Month In the moment.js

```
console.log("current month first date");
    const firstdate = moment().startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(firstdate);

console.log("current month last date");
    const lastdate=moment().endOf('month').format("DD-MM-YYYY"); 
console.log(lastdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("current month first date");
    const firstdate = moment().startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(firstdate);

console.log("current month last date");
    const lastdate=moment().endOf('month').format("DD-MM-YYYY"); 
console.log(lastdate);
```

// THIS IS THE SIMPLEST OF GETTING DATES IN MOMENTJS