# momentjs startOf('month') not working

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get the first and last date of a month:

```
let month = moment().month(2)
console.log(month, month.startOf('month'), month.endOf('month'))
```

They all print the same date: 
Sat Mar 31 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

Comment: see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267623/moment-js-get-first-and-last-day-of-current-month

Comment: calling startOf modifies the object in place, so by the time it is logged, console.log is logging `month` three times, and what is being logged is the last time `month` was modified, which is calling `endOf`