# How can I find how many business days left for the month using Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

hey guys I am trying to find the number working days for current month.

Using `moment-business-days` I could figure out how many business days are in between two dates. Also I could figure out how many business days are left for this week. But I am quite stuck on how to find how many business days are left for current month.

```
const diffDays = moment(secondDate).businessDiff(
  moment(firstDate),
  "days",
  true
); // this is where I find how many business days in between two dates

// and here how many business days left this week
const daysLeftThisWeek = 6 - moment(firstDate).day();
```

Comment: Go figure out how to get the last day for the current month, and then use that date …

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011797/10955263

Comment: @04FS thanks buddy it works