# bootstrap date picker only month and years

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap date picker for my angular js project.

below is the HTML

my date picker documentation is as below 
[date picker documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
   <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="fromDate"
    ng-required="newcashbenifit.isFixedAmount == false"
   ng-disabled="newcashbenifit.isFixedAmount == true"
    class="form-control" name="from" autocomplete="off"
   ng-model="newcashbenifit.fromDate" autoclose="false"
   data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy"  bs-datepicker />
```

date picker is loading and working well. but i need to modify this to show only month and years.
(remove dates). how i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `min-view="1"` attribute:

> Minimum allowed view - 0 | 1 | 2. 1 will only allow month selection.

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="fromDate"
   min-view="1"
   ng-required="newcashbenifit.isFixedAmount == false"
   ng-disabled="newcashbenifit.isFixedAmount == true"
   class="form-control" name="from" autocomplete="off"
   ng-model="newcashbenifit.fromDate" autoclose="false"
   data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy"  bs-datepicker />
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJkct8I71Gl7RYaK)</kbd>

Comment: thank you very much maxim.. This is amazing. God MAXIM <3

Comment: when i select month , i need to show last date of the month. currently it shows first day. do u have any idea ?

Comment: It does not support this behavior. When we talk about a month, it means the beginning of the month. So you you need to listen on `newcashbenifit.fromDate" ` modify it with `moment` lib for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267623/moment-js-get-first-and-last-day-of-current-month/39267750

Answer (score 0):

Use minViewMode:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    minViewMode: 1
});
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#minviewmode

Comment: can i use this jquery with angular js controller

Comment: what is this ID? textbox ID or ?

Comment: Try to get rid of using jQuery inside angularjs, it is bad practice

Comment: try using attribute to your input data-min-view-mode=1

Comment: Thanks Shivaji for the help