# How to get start and end dates from this iso formated structure using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have the `related.date: {"isoYear":"2021","isoWeek":"31"}`   property with the following value received from the backend. How can I receive first date and last date from isoWeek 31 for the isoYear by using momenjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `startOf('isoWeek')` and `endOf('isoWeek')` after you get `isoYear` from object and add `isoWeek` weeks:

```js
let related = {"isoYear":"2021","isoWeek":"31"};

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.isoWeek), 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.isoWeek), 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.isoWeek), 'weeks').startOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.isoWeek), 'weeks').endOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Now if you want to get month from `month` property you could do:

```js
let related = {"isoYear":"2021","isoWeek":"31", "month": "06"}

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.month) - 1, 'months').startOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))

console.log(moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.month) - 1, 'months').endOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note the `-1` on `add` function: this because in `moment` months number start from 0 (January).

Comment: It looks like it returns from Sunday not Monday

Comment: @NewTechLover yes, if you want that the first day of week is Monday you have to call `startOf('isoWeek')` and `endOf('isoWeek')`. I updated my answer

Comment: Last question will this structure work if I use it for isoMonth?

Comment: @NewTechLover yes it works, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267623/moment-js-get-first-and-last-day-of-current-month) question (I think `isoMonth` does not exists, `month` exists)

Comment: @NewTechLover I updated my answer with start and end month.

Comment: It returns invalid date on my side

Comment: @NewTechLover I can't see your code but on snippet it works. Let me see your code (just the line in which you use `startOf('month')`) and I will try to understand why is not working. Would be very useful if you could reproduce your error in codesandbox.

Comment: I have a month number which is 06 so I need to get start date and end date like did for the week I am using related.month  like this:
moment(related.isoYear).add(related.month , 'months').startOf('month'),
moment(related.isoYear).add(related.month , 'months').endOf('month'),

Also tried your sample but both are not working for month case

Comment: @NewTechLover watch better my answer: write `moment(related.isoYear)` is not sufficient for moment because you have to indicate the date format (YYYY). Then I see another error: `related.month` seems to be a string... but moment wants a number. So, please, modify your code in this way: `moment(related.isoYear, 'YYYY').add(parseInt(related.month), 'months').startOf('month')`

Comment: @NewTechLover I updated my answer with the startOf and endOf for month

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = moment().isoWeek(related.date.isoWeek).year(related.date.year)
const first = moment().weekday(0)
const last = moment().weekday(6)
```

by default the weekday 0 is sunday, if you live in an area where the first weekday is monday, you have to parse that on your own or use configured `moment-with-locales-es6`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think this approach will be a bit problematic for isoMonth since how last date is going to be found? Some months have 30 days some 31

Comment: In this case you could go to the first day of the following month (`moment().add(1, 'months')`) and subtract one day (`moment().subtract(1, 'days')`). This will give you the last day of the given month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startOf('isoWeek')`.

```js
// related.date: {"isoYear":"2021","isoWeek":"31"}
const related = {
  date: {
    isoYear: '2021',
    isoWeek: '31',
  },
};
const now = moment();
console.log(now.clone().isoWeek(Number(related.date.isoWeek)).startOf('isoWeek'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I receive value like this:
{"isoYear":"2021","isoWeek":"31"}

Not the usual object. I think firstly some conversion is needed