# Moment diff in months excluding days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to work out a difference in months between two dates without taking days into consideration.

I was trying to use `Math.ceil` but if the day in 2022 was ahead of the one in 2021 then I got 2 months instead of 1 month difference.

```js
const diff = moment([2022, 0, 1]).diff(moment([2021, 11, 3]), 'months', true);
console.log(diff); // 0.935483870967742, expected 1

const diffCeil = Math.ceil(
  moment([2022, 0, 3]).diff(moment([2021, 11, 1]), 'months', true)
);
console.log('diffCeil', diffCeil); // 2, expected 1

// Inaccurate diff doesn't work when 2021 day is bigger than in 2022
const inacurrateDiff = moment([2022, 0, 3]).diff(moment([2021, 11, 1]), 'months');
console.log('inacurrateDiff', inacurrateDiff); // 1, as expected
const inacurrateDiff2 = moment([2022, 0, 1]).diff(moment([2021, 11, 3]), 'months');
console.log('inacurrateDiff2', inacurrateDiff2); // 0, expected 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I did try it with and without `diff`'s third `precise` parameter.

Comment: Can't you just `Math.round`/`Math.floor` the first result ? Else, maybe this should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267623/moment-js-get-first-and-last-day-of-current-month

Comment: How exactly do you define "difference in months"? The number of months _ticked_ between the two dates? The number of 30 day intervals? Something else?

Comment: Diff in months ahead or back. If today's 16th of May, difference in months between 17th of April would be exactly 1 month. It shouldn't care about days, as long as the month is different we're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `startOf(d, 'month')` to compare start of months:

```
a.startOf('month').diff(b.startOf('month'), 'month');
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 2 because you're using `Math.ceil`, which always raises the fractional value to the next whole number.

There's no one right answer here, you'll have to decide how much of a fractional month you want to count.

For instance, if you want only **whole** months, use `Math.floor` rather than `Math.ceil`. If you want to count anything up to 1.5 months as one but 1.5 months and above as 2, use `Math.round`. Or you could set your own threshold, like 1.2 (it's a bit more work, but not that much).

Examples:

```js
function example(date1, date2) {
    const rawDiff = date1.diff(date2, "months", true);
    const diffFloored = Math.floor(rawDiff);
    const diffRounded = Math.round(rawDiff);
    const diffCeiled = Math.ceil(rawDiff);
    const neg = rawDiff < 0;
    const fractional = neg
        ? rawDiff + Math.trunc(rawDiff)
        : rawDiff - Math.trunc(rawDiff);
    const diffOnePointTwo = Math.abs(fractional) > 0.2
        ? Math.ceil(rawDiff)
        : Math.floor(rawDiff);

    console.log({
        date1: date1.toString(),
        date2: date2.toString(),
        rawDiff,
        diffFloored,
        diffRounded,
        diffCeiled,
        diffOnePointTwo,
    });
}

example(
    moment([2022, 0, 1]),
    moment([2021, 11, 3])
);
example(
    moment([2022, 0, 3]),
    moment([2021, 11, 1])
);
example(
    moment([2022, 0, 10]),
    moment([2021, 11, 1])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Only you and your project can say what definition you want to use.

Comment: I don't need a threshold, it doesn't have to be a whole month, it simple needs to be x months back or ahead. Surely that's possible.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk - So the difference between Dec 31st and Jan 1st of the following year is a month?