# MomentJs: endOf('month') does not deliver last day of month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

console.log of my initial date shows:

```
Fri Apr 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

This is what I do:

```
  // first day is guaranteed to be a first day of month by default
  var firstDayOfMonth = moment.utc(initialDate).startOf('day');
  var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.clone();
  lastDayOfMonth.endOf('month');
  console.log(firstDayOfMonth.toDate()); // Fri Apr 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
  console.log(lastDayOfMonth.toDate()); // Sun May 01 2016 01:59:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

**But last day of April is not May 1st of course.**

It might be related to a Summertime issue (CEST)? But i need it working in any timezone - I already try to set anything as UTC to get rid of these annoying timezone issues.

Comment: Date is shown in local time, while moment object is UTC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month see this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `moment.format()` instead of `toDate()` to get in UTC. For different formats refer `Multiple Locale Support` here https://momentjs.com/

For example,

```
console.log(lastDayOfMonth.format('LLLL')); 

output: Saturday, April 30, 2016 11:59 PM
```