# How to get the start date and end date of a month by passing Month and Year in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs, date-formatting

I am using Moment.js for calendar conversion. Is it possible to get the first and last date of the month by passing month and year.

Month and year format I have is - `10-18` which is in `MM-YY` format.

I want to get the first and last date of October for instance in `01 Oct 2018`. 
I can format it the date I want in Moment but was not sure how can I get the first and last date of a month by just passing `10-18`.

Any help suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks
R

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment JS start and end of given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131003/moment-js-start-and-end-of-given-month)

Comment: @Michael I believe you have sufficient rep to flag a question as a duplicate. Please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy, just use `startOf` and `endOf` ;)

Be careful as it mutates the original moment.

```js
const input = "10-18";
const output = moment(input, "MM-YY");
console.log('Start of the month:', output.startOf('month').format('LL'));
console.log('End of the month:', output.endOf('month').format('LL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Here is the doc:

- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/
- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so that it can serve the rest of the community ;)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.