# Find the first and last day of month based on the month number in Angular

Tags: html, angular, momentjs

I have an array with all months and the number of the month, like this :

```
  months = [
    { name: 'JANUARY', id: 0 },
    { name: 'FEBRUARY', id: 1 },
    { name: 'MARCH', id: 2 }
   ......
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26131085/7562674 it already have implementation.

getMonthDateRange(year, month) => current year : moment().year();  and for month will be selected month id.

Answer (score 0):

```
startAndEndOfSelectedMonth() {
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let startDate = moment([year, this.month - 1]);

    let endDate = moment(startDate).endOf('month');

    return { start: startDate, end: endDate };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this similar post (sharing the link below) will help you for achieving your goal. Concept remains the same.

**Link** [Get first and last date of current month with JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)