# How to make Monthly, semi-monthly date payment using js

Tags: javascript

pls check this my problem is similar to this [How to manage date using momentjs for a monthly payments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903953/how-to-manage-date-using-momentjs-for-a-monthly-payments)
The result what I want in Monthly is like this if the given date is `01-25-2022` and the terms is 3

```
Result
02-25-2022 
03-25-2022
04-25-2022
```

semi-monthly if the given date is `04-29-2022` and the terms is 3

```
Result
05-14-2022
05-29-2022
06-14-2022
```

```js
<!--FOR MONTHLY -->


var dateRelease = new Date("01-25-2022")

const terms = 3
for (let i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
  console.log(new Date(dateRelease.setDate(dateRelease.getDate() + 31)).toISOString().slice(0, 10))

}
```

```js
<!--FOR SEMI-MONTHLY -->


var dateRelease = new Date("04-29-2022")

const terms = 3
for (let i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
  console.log(new Date(dateRelease.setDate(dateRelease.getDate() + 15)).toISOString().slice(0, 10))

}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand  what do you exactly want ?

Comment: ohh sorry my problem is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903953/how-to-manage-date-using-momentjs-for-a-monthly-payments

Comment: You can not just add 31 or 15 days, the result will of course depend on how many days the starting month has to begin with. If you just want to advance a given date by "a month" in the colloquial sense, then you should be manipulating the month portion of the Date, not add 31 days. And your second case will probably require that you check how many days the current month has first.

Comment: Yes you're right, I have no idea how to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is made for this job.

```js
<!--FOR MONTHLY -->

var dateRelease = moment("2022-01-25")

const terms = 3
for (let i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
  console.log(dateRelease.add(1, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```js
<!--FOR SEMI-MONTHLY -->


var dateRelease = moment("2022-04-29")

const terms = 3
for (let i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
  console.log(dateRelease.add(2, 'weeks').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Monthly is good but how about the semi-monthly ? How can I dipslay out put like this `05-14-2022
05-29-2022
06-14-2022`

Comment: Semi-monthly usually is 2 weeks... And 2 weeks are 14 days on planet earth. That is what Moment gives here. But if you really want 15 days, you can do `.add(15, 'days')`.

Comment: Okay let say this is not a semi-monthly but how ca I get the this result if the given date is `04-29-2022` the return date is like this `05-14-2022`
`05-29-2022`
`06-14-2022`